# Retrieve data from SurfaceView to an Activity Class

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, surfaceview

I'm quite new to android development and I'm trying to connect a joystick that sends data via bluetooth. The Joystick is in a SurfaceView and I want to be able retrieve the data on x and y coordinates on the joystick in my Activity class to be able to send the data via bluetooth.
I've tried to look up similar issues on the web but cant make it work.

Here's my onDraw method in the SurfaceView:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, float zx, float zy){

    dx = x-zx;
    dy = y-zy;



    super.onDraw(canvas);



    canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, (canvas.getWidth() - canvas.getWidth() / 7) - background.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight() / 4) - background.getHeight() / 2, null);
    canvas.drawText(Float.toString(x), 60, 60, paint1);
    canvas.drawText(Float.toString(y), 60, 120, paint1);

    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, (canvas.getWidth()-canvas.getWidth() / 7) - ball.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight()-canvas.getHeight() / 4) - ball.getHeight() / 2, null);

    }
    else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x - ball.getWidth() / 2, y - ball.getHeight() / 2, null);
    }
}
```

It's also running an AsyncTask:

```
public class MySurfaceThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    CustomSurfaceView cSurfaceView;


    public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder sh, CustomSurfaceView csv){
        mSurfaceHolder = sh;
        cSurfaceView = csv;
        x = y = 0;

        cSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                System.out.println(x + " " + y);

                calculateValues(x,y);

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        x = y = 0;
                        dx = dy = 0;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private float calculateValues(float xx, float yy){
                dx = xx-zeroX;
                dy = yy-zeroY;
                angle = (float)Math.atan(Math.abs(dy / dx));
                c = (float)Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                if(c > radius){
                    if (dx > 0 && dy > 0) { //lower right corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX + radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY + radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx > 0 && dy < 0){ //top right corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX + radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY - radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx < 0 && dy < 0){ //top left corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX - radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY - radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                    else if(dx < 0 && dy > 0){ //lower left corner
                        xx = (float) (zeroX - radius * Math.cos(angle));
                        yy = (float) (zeroY + radius * Math.sin(angle));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    xx = zeroX + dx;
                    yy = zeroY + dy;
                }
                System.out.println("dx: " + dx);
                System.out.println("dy: " + dy);
                System.out.println(angle);
                x = xx;
                y = yy;

            return angle;
            }
        });


    }
```

And here's my Activity Class.

```
public class SendInput extends Activity {

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice btDevice;
BluetoothSocket btSocket;
OutputStream os;
InputStream in;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAcc;
private int BTSTATE = 0, SensorStatus=0;
int MouseReq=0, read_values=0;
private static final UUID MY_UUID =UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String address = getIntent().getStringExtra("address").trim();
    btDevice=btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BluetoothConnect.start();
}
```

Appreciate all the help i can get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're overriding `onDraw()`, rather than drawing on the SurfaceView Surface, you should forget SurfaceView and just use a custom View (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). AsyncTask is for low-priority background operations, and doesn't really make sense here. You'll need to be more specific about what isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @fadden. I'm not overriding onDraw in the SurfaceView. The Joystick is working and printing out x and y coordinates. More Specifically: I want to be able to access the value in the "angle"-variable in the AsyncTaks from my Activity class. Any Idea?